# Passing exit code from Powershell to Linux Bash Shell Script

Tags: powershell, shell, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using WSL Windows Subsystem for Linux on a UBuntu 20 distribution on windows 10.
I am running a shell script that needs to call a Powershell script and get its return code.
On powershell I have a script that on certain conditions exits with 1:

```
## Executing DTSX package DataF\DTS\B2F_ENT2QS_DELTAS1.dtsx on Server DATAF-SSISD.marte.gbes\SQL01Q,10101
## Package executed with error: Cannot access the package or the package does not exist. Verify that the package exists and that the user has permissions to it.
 Msg 27146, Level 16, State 1, Procedure create_execution, Line 190.
1
## ReturnCode Powershell: 0
```

As you can see 1 is returned on the exit of the powershell script, however on shell script I get the $? and it returns 0.

Here is my shellscript:

```
"${PowerShellLocation}" -Command ${pws}
ReturnCode=$?
echo "## ReturnCode Powershell:" ${ReturnCode}
```

Here is powershell script:

```
catch {
    $message = "## Package executed with error: " + $PSItem.ToString()
    Write-Host $message
   
    return 1
    exit 1
```

Any ideas on what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Actually, taking a closer look: `return 1` (which _returns data_) would prevent `exit 1` (which sets an _exit code_) from taking effect - or is the presence of both statements just a posting artifact?

Comment: @mklement0 you are TOTALLY right! I commented that one out and left only the exit. It worked. The thing is return 1 or return 0 was there because if the script would be called by another powershell script it could have a value (like a function). Thanks a lot!